# Is it possible for an HTTP server to interrupt and replace a response in progress?

Tags: http, error-handling, large-files

Supposing I was to stream a large response to a browser, or other HTTP client; is there a way for the server to return an HTTP 500 error page mid-way through the download?

For example, I may be serving a very large HTML page, or perhaps displaying a large JPEG file in its own tab, and the data-source is terminated prematurely. At this point I want to show my standard HTTP 500 error page.

If it helps, I can use `Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, or even other hackish HTTP headers to make this work.

Is it possible to override a download result on the HTTP level?

I know one could add a JavaScript `alert` if the response were in HTML format, but I'm just wondering if I can override / restart the response on the HTTP level instead?